# html page with frameset tag not working

Tags: html

Can any one tell me whats wrong with the following code..

**managerhomepage.html**

```
 <html>
  <head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body> 
    <frameset row="20%,80%">
        <frame src="managerhomepage.jsp">
        <frame src="signup.html">
    </frameset>
 </body>
</html>
```

**managerhomepage.jsp**

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

  <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>ManagerHomePage</title>
    <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <% String[] name={"Raviteja","Pramod","Aadinarayana","Anusha","Ramireddy","Surendhra","Rajesh","Aruna"};%>
    <center>
            <div id="border"><div id="header">
                <div id="logo-bg">
                    <div class="name">Ayansys</div>
                    <div class="tag">COMPANY SLOGAN</div>
                </div>
           </div>
                <h1>MANAGER'S HOME PAGE</h1>
                Select a SalesPerson from here <select name="salespersons">
                    <option></option>
                   <% for(int i=0;i<name.length;i++){
                        %><option><%=name[i]%></option><%
                   }%>
                </select>
                <input type="button" value="OK"/>
    </center>
</body>
 </html>
```

**signup.html**

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <title>SIGNUP</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script language="JavaScript" src="ts_picker.js">
    </script>
     </head>
      <body>
    <center>
            <div id="border"><div id="header">
                <div id="logo-bg">
                    <div class="name">Ayansys</div>
                    <div class="tag">COMPANY SLOGAN</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h1>SIGNUP FORM</h1>
            <form action="managerhomepage.html">
                <table>
                    <tr><td>FIRST NAME</td><td><input type="text" name="fname" size="50"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>LAST NAME</td><td><input type="text" name="sname" size="50"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>DESIRED LOGIN NAME</td><td><input type="text" name="login" size="50"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>PASSWORD</td><td><input type="password" name="pwd" size="50"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>RE-TYPE PASSWORD</td><td><input type="password" name="repwd" size="50"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>GENDER</td><td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"/>Male<input type="radio" name="gender" value="FeMale"/>Female</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>DATE OF BIRTH</td><td><form name="tstest">
                                                    <input type="text" readonly size="47" name="timestamp" value="">
                                                    <a href="javascript:show_calendar('document.tstest.timestamp', document.tstest.timestamp.value);"><img src="cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Click Here to Pick up the timestamp"></a>
                                                    </form></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>MAIL ID</td><td><input type="text" name="mail1" size="30">@<input type="text" name="mail2" size="11"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>EMPLOYEE ID</td><td><input type="text" name="eid" size="50"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>TYPE OF USER</td><td><input type="radio" name="manager"/>Manager<input type="radio" name="seniormanager"/>SeniorManager</td></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>ADDRESS</td><td><textarea rows="9" cols="40"></textarea></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>MOBILE NUMBER</td><td><input type="text" size="50" name="mobile"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td></td><td><input type="SUBMIT" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" name="cancel" value="CANCEL"/></td></tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            </form>
                </br><div>Designed by:<a href="#">STUDY CENTER</a></div>
          </div>
    </center>
</body>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`frameset` is used **instead** of `body`, not inside it.

Answer (score 4):

The attribute is `rows`, not `row`.

[Validating](http://validator.w3.org/) would have told you this.

Answer (score 1):

A frameset is used to establish a BODY, and should not be used inside of one.
Plus: You don't have a BASE target="" in your framed pages head(s).
And DIVS can be used to establish what you are trying to acheive, but referencing them can become complex quickly.
Also, naming your frames makes them much easier to deal with, and I see you've left their name references out of their declarations. There was alot of frameset debate when it was standardized, and if you are a professional author, I would suggest reading some of that information so you can see the advantages and disadvantages of framesets.

Now, with that being said, I would offer this suggestion:

IFRAME might work for you in this case, but because of the resourses and load times, esp. with building data tables, I would suggest another approach.